# Having trouble to write an Oracle SQL query

Tags: oracle, date, group-by

I have a simple table `T(NAME, DATE, VALUE)`

What I want is to get the difference between `VALUE` of the row containing the oldest `DATE` and the one containing the earliest `DATE`, all this grouped by `NAME`.

I can't manage to write this into a single query.

Any help would be more than welcome, I have no idea how to perform this.

Comment: Analytics function shoud help https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions

Comment: @pifor Thanks I'm gonna check this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option; sample data is from line #1 - 8; query you might need begins at line #10.

```
SQL> with t(name, datum, value) as
  2  -- sample data
  3    (select 'LF', date '2020-01-01', 100 from dual union all
  4     select 'LF', date '2020-04-13', 200 from dual union all
  5     select 'LF', date '2020-05-26', 555 from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 'ST', date '2020-03-13', 600 from dual
  8    )
  9  -- query
 10  select distinct
 11    name,
 12    maxval - minval diff
 13  from (select name,
 14          first_value(value) over (partition by name order by datum desc) maxval,
 15          first_value(value) over (partition by name order by datum asc)  minval
 16        from t
 17       );

NA       DIFF
-- ----------
LF        455
ST          0

SQL>
```

Comment: Oh that exactly it! Thanks a lot, I need to pratice this kind of query I have no experience with `partition by` and `over`